# ImageMagick installed in Ubuntu Server which is found in Php.info, but not working

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have installed ImageMagick php library in my ubuntu server using the following command:

```
apt-get install php5-gd php5-idn php-pear php5-imagick
```

I could find the ImageMagick module shown in php.info file, but when I tried to use it's function in my php program, it doesn't seems to be working and even I don't have any errors too.

Please Help, I am a new user.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What function?  What Ubuntu/PHP versions? Older versions will not have support for new features.

Comment: Thanks for your imm. reply. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and PHP 5.3.2-1. I could see imagemagick enabled in php.info, but when I try to run any function of imagemagick for uploading and resizing image function, I don't get any output. Tried with a following small code too:

<?php
$resource = NewMagickWand();
MagickReadImage( $resource, 'image.jpg' );

 header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
 MagickEchoImageBlob( $resource );

$width = MagickGetImageWidth( $resource );
$height = MagickGetImageHeight( $resource );
echo "Image size, in pixels, is:  width $width x height $height";
?>

Answer (score 1):

Install php5-cli

```
apt-get install php5-cli
```

Test php5-imagick:

```
php /usr/share/doc/php5-imagick/examples/polygon.php > ~/polygon.png
```